# Flutter asset folder path

Tags: flutter, assets

I want to build an app with multiple flavors, which work very well. But now I have the requirement to include static json files into my preview app, because sometime the backend differs in development speed. So I can use the json files within my app as fake/mock data.

Hard requirements are:

- Preview has jsons included
- Production should be release without any unused files (no jsons files)

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: what does it mean "Preview has jsons included
"

Comment: you can also fetch data from remote and save if to tmp space or shared pref for later use, instead of hardcoded jsons, that way you can dynamically change the json as well in future

Comment: My preview version needs to be offline usable, that's why I need the response jsons within my binary - but only for preview and not for production. Oh, one additional information: I don't have access to the backend, that's why I can't put the fixture there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the data. If JSON will not change anymore or rarely change, you can just load JSON from the local asset. Otherwise, getting the JSON data from the cloud is a better way. It's more flexible.

Comment: I need my mock jsons within the binary. If I put them on the server, they will be like normal responses. That's not my plan, to setup fixtures on a different server.